# Genesis and Mega Drive Classics Collection: PAL or NTSC versions? Are games in these two packs the same?

Tags: emulation, version-differences, sega-genesis, digital-distribution

Are these games PAL or NTSC versions? Or maybe it's PAL for the Mega Drive collection and NTSC for Genesis ROMs? Are there any other differences between games in those two Sega bundles?

I wasn't able to find these details on Steam or Amazon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the Genesis and Mega Drive collections are NTSC versions, widely regarded to be the better ones due to the fact that PAL versions usually ran slower.

However, there are a few odd things that seem to be running at PAL speed (50hz rather than 60) like the announcer's voice in Virtua Fighter 2. This is probably just an emulation issue.

Comment: Looking through Steam I noticed one more interesting thing. It looks like on the title screen of "Alien Soldier" (at least according to the screenshots present there) some "Engrish" text from the Japanese NTSC version is missing. I mean this "VISUALSHOCK! SOUNDSHOCK! ..." part. It was actually removed from the EU PAL version, read more here: http://segaretro.org/Alien_Soldier#Version_differences If this on Steam is not a PAL version, where does it come from? There was no US release, except from a mysterious Sega Channel version...

Comment: It's either running a 'fixed' NTSC version(personally, I hate it when people 'fix' games in retro collections), but considering the other 'quirky' text is still there(difficulty settings are only 'supereasy' and 'superhard', amusingly) it's more likely running the PAL version but under a 60hz(NTSC) mode-of-sorts. You can set a game to either PAL/NTSC in most emulators regardless of if the game even released in the other setting. My idea would be the emulation is under a constant NTSC setting even if there is no offical NTSC version. So an offical... unoffical. If that makes any sense at all.

Comment: I see... And how do you actually know that the Mega Drive collection is in the NTSC format as well? I'm asking because I want to mark this answer as "accepted". :)

Comment: Games have less PAL/NTSC differences than others, but the easiest way to tell is through Sonic the Hedgehog 1. Infamously, the European PAL version was much slower than the NTSC and pretty much ruined the game. If you search up "Sonic 1 PAL vs NTSC" on YouTube, you'll find what I'm talking about.

Comment: [Oh, and here's Green Hill Zone PAL version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NH4nvZ02T8o). Us Europeans had it rough for a while, man :P

Comment: Oh, you're from the UK, so you actually were able to test the Mega Drive collection. I don't know why I thought you're from the US. :p